# Group data from multiple columns in a csv in Python by timestamps over a defined time range

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

Here is what I am trying to do, which I am getting stuck on: Need to be able to group and graph various rows in various columns of data in a csv file by when the data was recorded, either occurred during the daytime or nighttime (defined as sunrise i.e. 6:18 am CDT to sunset i.e. 7:27 pm CDT).I have hundreds of days worth of data to analyze. I have multiple csv files to use and compare, but need to compare/correlate night time results versus daytime results, with other data. Since sunrise and sunset times vary day to day, I have made an excel (csv file) which has the times for Sunrise and Sunset listed in separate columns for each day. Also, how to plot and group said data by week or day over that defined range of time (daylight vs nighttime). Please help a struggling science student who isn't strong in Python coding but eager to learn!

Sample Data from csv file (each time stamp interval is 30 mins over many days)

```
    Timestamp        Avg Conc for 30 min    Avg. Wind
    5/20/2014 18:30              4.56789        31.23
    5/20/2014 19:00              5.67890        42.34
    5/20/2014 19:30              3.45678        23.45
    5/20/2014 20:00              6.54321        34.56
    5/20/2014 20:30              4.12345        41.23
    5/20/2014 21:00              3.98765        19.87
```

Sample Data Set#2 (sunrise and sunset time)

```
    Date          Sunrise          Sunset
    5/20/2014     5:33:00          20:06:00
    5/21/2014     5:32:00          20:07:00
    5/22/2014     5:31:00          20:08:00
    5/23/2014     5:31:00          20:08:00
```

My issues are how to pull from separate csv files, arrange over this time range (Daylight = time within sunrise until sunset) round up at >=15 mins to next 30 min interval, if <15 round down to previous 30 minute interval. I want to then be able to plot that on a graph to compare the daylight vs nighttime data to analyze.

I thank anyone and everyone in advance who can assist me with a task most might deem easy or simple, but complex to a Python novice such as myself.

EDITS: Here is the code i used to read in the files...

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime

    flux = pd.read_csv('C:\step4n5.csv')
    weather = pd.read_csv('C:\Weather_Data.csv')

    header1 = flux.next() #header
    header2 = weather.next()

    for for Timestamp, Avg Flux Concentration (Fc) in flux:
        Timestamp = datetime.strptime(Timestamp, "%M-%d-%y %H:%M:%S")
    for Date, Sunrise, Sunset in weather:
        Date = datetime.strptime(Date, "%M-%d-%y")
        Sunrise
```

I got stuck here. Not sure if i read/strp the timestamp properly.

Comment: You got a lot going on with this question :-).  Do you have multiple 'observation' files in the same format and one sunrise/sunset file?

Comment: Yes. The sunrise/sunset is one csv file. And the other file has numerous columns which i would want to compare against the nightime vs daytime values.

Comment: Ok, use pandas read_csv(() to import them

Comment: Yeah, as Bob notes, you have a lot going on here.  You're likely to get more help if you do this in steps and show your work.  Just start by reading (or at least trying to read) all the data sets, and go from there.

Comment: Here are the sample data file links:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3972uqY0U8MdFRoTDAzZXlLNmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Additional Sample Data file links:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3972uqY0U8MWnZUaUhvcTJ2eFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn't be too tough to accomplish in a number of different ways.  As others have suggested, you could include a little more data and show more of your work to get a more explicit answer.  Its tough to tell if you have already moved your DataFrame into a time series or not.

The best path forward would be to post the CSVs with a little more data and show the commands you have used to read the data, so we can see whether you have datetime functionality yet and what data types the columns are.

Assuming your columns are just regular columns a pretty inefficient method that should work just fine for 100s of days with 48 rows per day is to do a double for loop and add the sunrise and sunset times as extra columns on the first DataFrame.  You can then add yet another daytime column based on logic of whether the time is between sunrise and sunset.  I know this is pretty hand wavey, but something like:

```
#Create a new date only column from the first part of the timestamp:
df1['Date']=string(df1.Datetime)[0:9]
#Create a new time only column from the second half of the timestamp
#and convert hours and minutes into minutes:
df1['Time']=int(string(df1.Datetime)[10:12])*60+int(string(df1.Datetime)[13:15])
#Create new sunrise and sunset columns
import numpy as np
df1["sunrise"] = np.nan
df1["sunset"] = np.nan
for row in df1:
    for row2 in df2:
        if row.Date==row2.Date:
            df1.sunrise=df2.sunrise
            df1.sunset=df2.sunset
#add in the daylight column if it is between sunrise and sunset
df['daylight']=df1.Time>int(string(df1.sunrise[0:2])*60+int(string(df1.sunrise)[3:5] and df1.Time<int(string(df1.sunset[0:2])*60+int(string(df1.sunset)[3:5]
```

i.e. df.daylight will be a Boolean for whether it is daylight or not.  This might be buggy, but you probably gather the guest of it.

You can then query the Boolean to recover only daylight or nighttime items with:

```
df[df.daylight==True]
df[df.daylight==False]
```

The datetime functionality will allow you to use the 'between' functionality. And you can also convert between hours and minutes if pandas knows that these are times, which I'm pretty sure it will (depending on how you read things in).

Hope this helps!  Someone like Wes McKinney can probably jump in with a 2 line way to accomplish this :-)

Comment: Here are the sample data file links:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3972uqY0U8MdFRoTDAzZXlLNmc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Additional Sample Data file links:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3972uqY0U8MWnZUaUhvcTJ2eFk/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this.  So given your data frames (flux, weather) from above

We'll start by creating a new column called Date in your flux frame.  This will be the date part of Timestamp which is most likely a string based on how you imported it.  We'll also convert Timestamp to the date time format using pd.to_datetime()

```
flux["Date"] = flux["Timestamp"].map(lambda d : d.split(" ")[0]) #gotta be a better way
flux["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(flux["Timestamp"])
flux

Timestamp   Avg Conc for 30 min Avg. Wind   Date
0   2014-05-20 18:30:00  4.56789     31.23   5/20/2014
1   2014-05-20 19:00:00  5.67890     42.34   5/20/2014
2   2014-05-20 19:30:00  3.45678     23.45   5/20/2014
3   2014-05-20 20:00:00  6.54321     34.56   5/20/2014
4   2014-05-20 20:30:00  4.12345     41.23   5/20/2014
5   2014-05-20 21:00:00  3.98765     19.87   5/20/2014
```

Now lets combine flux and weather into one frame using merge()

```
combined = pd.merge(flux,weather,on="Date")
combined
    Timestamp   Avg Conc for 30 min Avg. Wind   Date    Sunrise Sunset
0   2014-05-20 18:30:00  4.56789     31.23   5/20/2014   5:33:00     20:06:00
1   2014-05-20 19:00:00  5.67890     42.34   5/20/2014   5:33:00     20:06:00
2   2014-05-20 19:30:00  3.45678     23.45   5/20/2014   5:33:00     20:06:00
3   2014-05-20 20:00:00  6.54321     34.56   5/20/2014   5:33:00     20:06:00
4   2014-05-20 20:30:00  4.12345     41.23   5/20/2014   5:33:00     20:06:00
5   2014-05-20 21:00:00  3.98765     19.87   5/20/2014   5:33:00     20:06:00
```

Now we combine and convert our Date and Sunrise/Sunset columns.

```
combined["Sunrise"] = pd.to_datetime(combined["Date"] + " " + combined["Sunrise"])
combined["Sunset"] = pd.to_datetime(combined["Date"] + " " + combined["Sunset"])
combined
```

Since we merged our two data frames we can utilize pandas boolean indexing and update a new column called TOW

```
rowindex = (combined["Timestamp"] > combined["Sunrise"]) & (combined["Timestamp"] < combined["Sunset"])
combined.loc[rowindex,"TOW"] = "daytime"
combined.loc[~rowindex,"TOW"] = "nightime"  # ~ is used as a "not"
combined[["Timestamp","Avg Conc for 30 min","Avg. Wind","TOW"]] #subset of combined

    Timestamp   Avg Conc for 30 min Avg. Wind   TOW
0   2014-05-20 18:30:00  4.56789     31.23   daytime
1   2014-05-20 19:00:00  5.67890     42.34   daytime
2   2014-05-20 19:30:00  3.45678     23.45   daytime
3   2014-05-20 20:00:00  6.54321     34.56   daytime
4   2014-05-20 20:30:00  4.12345     41.23   nightime
5   2014-05-20 21:00:00  3.98765     19.87   nightime
```

Comment: Great reply Mr. Haffner. How would i graph/group all of the daytime TOW values together? How would i graph/group the nightime TOW? For example, if i wanted to plot a weeks worth of all the daylight Avg. Wind?

Comment: Thanks, will do. You are a blessing! Thank you so much for your help and for getting me pointed in the right direction!

Comment: No problem.  Give what I suggested a shot, look at group by() and post another Question if you need help

Comment: Getting errors when i input the following script combined["Sunrise"] = pd.to_datetime(combined["Date"] + " " + combined["Sunrise"])
combined["Sunset"] = pd.to_datetime(combined["Date"] + " " + combined["Sunset"])

Comment: combined["Sunrise"] = pd.to_datetime(combined["Date"] + " " + combined["Sunrise"])

Comment: It keeps causing an Key Error: "Sunrise"

Comment: This is all that I have above your script exactly as it is written: import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from datetime import datetime

    flux = pd.read_csv('C:\step4n5.csv')
    weather = pd.read_csv('C:\Weather_Data.csv')